# How to extract all alphabetical characters from a string and store as a 1-dim array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, alphabetical

I have a variable `$var = "My name's Ankit"`. I want to store all the English alphabet characters of `$var` into an array `$charvar`. I know that I can use a simple for loop over the entire length of `$var` and `array_push` the characters if they are English characters else ignore. However, I wanted to know if PHP provides some function which can do this. 
What I want in `$charvar` is:

```
Array
(
        [0] => M
        [1] => y
        [2] => n
        [3] => a
        [4] => m
        [5] => e
        [6] => s
        [7] => A
        [8] => n
        [9] => k
        [10] => i
        [11] => t
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are not good enough.

This does EXACTLY what you want in one step / one function.  Split the string on zero or more non-alphabetical characters.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jBZVo)):

```
$var = "My name's Ankit";
$charvar = preg_split('/[^a-z]*/i', $var, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_export($charvar);
```

Output: (no subarrays)

```
array (
  0 => 'M',
  1 => 'y',
  2 => 'n',
  3 => 'a',
  4 => 'm',
  5 => 'e',
  6 => 's',
  7 => 'A',
  8 => 'n',
  9 => 'k',
  10 => 'i',
  11 => 't',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/763453)

```
preg_match_all("![a-zA-Z0-9]!", "My name's Ankit",$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => M
            [1] => y
            [2] => n
            [3] => a
            [4] => m
            [5] => e
            [6] => s
            [7] => A
            [8] => n
            [9] => k
            [10] => i
            [11] => t
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to strip away all characters and leave only those you want. Let us assume `$s` is where the string is stored. To select only alphabets, try;

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $s);
```

To add numbers to the mix, try;

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $s);
```

You can play around with it for any other characters.

For your case;

```
$var = "My name's Ankit"
$charvar = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $var);
```

Let me know if it helps.